# How do i show <Div> each time button clicked

Tags: html, angularjs

How do i show `<Div`> each time `<Button>` is clicked.
Following is my default `<Div>` and it has `Add` button.

The default `Div` will always remain visible. But when user click Add Button, a new div should show under default div and so on.... `If user clicks Add button 5 times than 5 <Div> should show with same controls/inputs under default <Div>.`

Any suggest?

**Code:**

```
<div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
    <button ng-click="addStudent = true" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add new Student
    </button>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label required">Roll No.</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" id="rollNo" name="runNumber" class="form-control" data-ng-model="RollNumber" ng-required="true" maxlength="100" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Student Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" name="studentName" class="form-control" data-ng-model="StudentName" maxlength="500" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Class Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="text" name="Class" class="form-control" data-ng-model="ClassName" maxlength="500" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think ng-repeat would be an easy way to do this, maybe make an array and push +1 into it every time you want to add something (and repeat this html on it)

Comment: ajmajmajma, thanks i got the idea.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you are having trouble, let me know and I could provide an example.

Comment: I am facing problem one step further. I am able to do what i asked in my question but now if i type in RollNo of 1st div than it is also being typed in every RollNo field of all other divs... How could i handle it?

Comment: if you typing something static in a repeat, it will be the same static value in every iteration of the repeat. Sounds like you are doing the ng-repeat on the class="form-group" divs when you should probably be doing it on the class="panel-body form-horizontal" div itself, unless you need to repeat items individually inside.

Comment: What difference it will create if put repeat on class="panel-body form-horizontal" div?

Comment: You'd be repeating over that whole html snipped you have there instead of individual pieces of it. If you need dynamic titles in an ng-repeat too you can use a repeat on an object with values inside of the dynamic stuff.

Comment: Lets say i continue by keeping ng-repeat where it is right now. Is there a way i can set data-ng-model dynamically in AngularJs/

Comment: Yeah, run the repeat over a list of objects, each object representing each item in the repeat.